# How to format a Double coming from a Object in Java?

Tags: java, android

I want to format a `Double` obtained from an `Object` so it only displays three digits after the decimal point. Here's the current code:

```
 Three a = Data.get(index); 
 // Get the y-axis acceleration value
 double b = a.getY();
 String accelerationOutUnfiltered = Double.toString(b);
 Data[0] = accelerationOutUnfiltered;
```

Note: I am doing this in Android, and when I use `String.format("%.3f", y)` this doesn't work and it throws me a error in Android Studio. Currently the above code works but it displays 15 digits after the decimal point.

I have tried several forms, but they all have failed. Please help. Thanks :)

Comment: you should use decimalFormat class as inn the answer below... can we see the code you try????

Comment: Also refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java

Comment: What is the error you're getting from String.format("%.3f", y)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `DecimalFormatter`.

For example:

```
double b = a.getY();

DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
formatter.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);

String formattedDouble = formatter.format(b);
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you. Now, I need to do it for formatting three values to write them in a file.   I tried:   
                String a= formatter2.format(g, h, i);           But it doesn't work.

Comment: Format the values separately, and then concatenate them into one `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Have tried decimal formatter?

You do something like this:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#####");
df.format(<your_number>);
```